# How to get the content of another page without loading in browser

Tags: php, jquery, asp-classic

**Context:**

There is an `asp` page in another web site that contains a search form. After submitting this form with the search value, the page displays the results of the search in an iframe.

**Question:**

I want to use the returned result in my page without loading that page in browser. I have got permission from the other web site administrator. I know php and jQuery. How should I proceed?

**Example:** 

`abcd.asp` contains a form which contains  `<input name="regno"/>` and a submit button. The form submits to itself and results Name, date of birth and Marks is returned in table format in an iframe.

**Notes:**

I have a page with same `<input>` and upon submitting it will use the above `asp` page and get details and display it in my page.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

1. Use jQuery to submit your page via AJAX to a local PHP file.
2. When the local PHP file gets the request, do a curl post request to your remote page and fetch the results.
3. Return these results in your local PHP script so that these will be available to your AJAX request
4. Your ajax request now has the remote contents, so just use jQuery to push them into the document.

Comment: This is way too complicated. You only need jQuery to perform an ajax call. Even if it is a call to a different server.

Comment: @FriederikeS - no you can't do it like you say. You cannot do ajax request to a remote domain(well, not easily). What you can do, is jsonp requests but that server should provide a proper response for the jsonp callback, so yes, my answer is still valid and easy to do.

Comment: Yes you have a point. If you're using HTTP GET you also have to use jsonp to do it with jQuery only. Difficulty always depends on the knowledge of the developer though. ;)
But: with HTTP POST you don't need to use jsonp. You can make a request to another domain. The other domain must then decide if it will allow cross-domain requests or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AJAX to perform this task. It loads a particular section of data without reloading a page. More info about what is ajax is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534632/WhatplusisplusAJAX-3f)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use [jQuery's ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To make this work with different domains you need to enable crossdomain support. This is very easy in jQuery:

```
$.support.cors = true; // enable cross domain support
```

Now you can make a request to another domain. Of course the server on that domain must also accept cross-domain requests. ;)

**Option 1 - HTTP GET & JSONP**

As Twisted1919 pointed out you have to use jsonp if you want to make a HTTP GET request. If you're not familiar with jsonp It requires a bit of reading to understand the concept. But there is excellent support for this in jQuery (as described in [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)).

**Option 2 - HTTP POST**

If you're using http post to make your request you can simply use jQuery.post() for this. With cros domain enabled an the server accepting your request this should work out of the box.